# How to connect a Veth with a Podman network?

Tags: networking, containers, podman, bridge

I would like to connect a Veth point to a network podman already created (with containers in it) but I can not do it

```
podman network create mon_network
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
podman network attach mon_network veth1
```

and it gives : Error: unrecognized command `podman network attach`

So i tried :
`podman network connect mon_network veth1`

the results : Error: no container with name or ID "veth1" found: no such container

Can someone help me please  :(

Comment: If you do `podman help network connect` then it says `Usage: podman network connect [options] NETWORK CONTAINER` which explains your error message. I'm afraid I don't know how to attach a new interface to an existing network though